# Started a new job, received minimal training. My manager is my main point of contact and is unapproachable

Tags: new-job, manager

I started a new job 4 months ago and this was a career pivot for me as I entered a new industry. I also went from working for a company of 50 people to 15000 people so fairly new to the corporate lifestyle.

My manager did interview me and is very well aware of this industry being new for me. Upon joining, I was barely given any training sessions, rather was just told to learn everything myself by using the web. I took it as a challenge and kept giving my manager frequent updates however never got a response/feedback if I am following the correct path.

Once training period was over, it was tough to get any job expectations and responsibilities clear from my manager as he would never attend any meeting we scheduled. He had excuses of running late, that he will meet at a later time but there was never any initiative from his end and I had to keep following up with him. Anytime my manager says he will meet me, it easily gets pushed 2 weeks for one reason or the other. When we do meet he answers my questions, gives me tasks for the next week. There are also instances where he has to get back to me on something/send me resources to move forward/ connect me with SPOCs but it rarely ever happens as he forgets or puts it low on his priority list which in turn affects my productivity and keeps me stuck to a point where I have to remind him a couple times.

Earlier this was a new and I gave him the benefit of doubt but now it is more like a pattern of me running after him for giving me resources to succeed at my job. There is also no clear communication/ transparency from his end and I rarely get replies from him on teams.

How can I bring it up with him/senior manager as I do not want this to come bite me later.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: Ask for feedback, nothing wrong with wanting to learn and know how you're going especially when new.  This question has come up before (and answered before) hence I've voted to close it as you will find useful answers there.

Comment: Has there been any voicing of complaints about you meeting your goals, or any mentions on a similar topic? I can't prove it either way but it's possible you might just be expecting to be micromanaged more than you actually are. What you're describing is not unheard of in large company structures.

Comment: Are you working alone or part of a team?  If you are a part of a team do they indicate this is normal behavior for the manager, and if this is normal for the manager how do they handle it?

Answer (score 3):

You may be expected to ask your peers to help you self-study. Ask them to recommend how to get started, or if there's something you could be helping with that would teach you about the product. Read documentation. Read the design.  Read the task management system and look for low-hanging fruit that you could get started on.

Answer (score 2):

Just be patient.

Some companies simply move slower than others with new employees.  Your manager may be extremely busy or they may be purposely giving you tasks very slowly to make sure that you are properly acclimated to the specific procedures/environment of your company.  This doesn't mean that you should stop sending reminders and following up.  Continue to do so.  If your manager has any issue with your persistence they would (hopefully) let you know.

In the meantime, take advantage of any downtime to learn anything you can that is possibly relevant to your job role.  Try to get to know your coworkers to get a feel for how things are done at this company.  Maybe this is a company wide experience, maybe it is just your manager.  Regardless, just keep seeking things to do instead of just sitting around doing nothing.  You were hired for a reason, it just may take a bit longer than you expected for that reason to be fulfilled.